# How to get callerid using asterisk

Tags: asterisk

my scenario is below

analog phone (10 to 99)------> pbx------>(77)asterisk--------> jitsi(2000)

i have analog telephone interface numbered 77 attached with asterisk and
other sip user is 2000 on jitsi.

I can call from any number from 10 to 99(in intercom) on 77 and ivr
response will come then i can typed 2000# and call go to 2000 named user
in asterisk.

Now my problem is when i am calling from 10 to 99 (any number) this number
should display to sip 2000's user. But its not showing to user. Its shows
asterisk@my_asterisk_server_ip.

my config. as follow

extension.conf

```
exten => s,1,Goto(phrase-menu,s,1)

[phrase-menu]

exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,2,Wait(1)
exten => s,3,Read(PHRASEID,/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/custom/soip)
exten => s,4,Wait(2)
exten => s,5,Set(CALLERID(num,CID)=${CALLERID})
exten => s,6,Dial(SIP/${PHRASEID},40,tT)
exten => h,1,Hangup()
```

and in chan_dahdi.conf

```
; General options
[channels]
usecallerid=yes
hidecallerid=no
callwaiting=yes
threewaycalling=yes
transfer=yes
echocancel=yes
echocancelwhenbridged=yes
cidsignalling=dtmf
cidstart=polarity
callerid=asreceived
rxgain=0.0
txgain=0.0
;FXO Modules
group=1
echocancel=yes
signalling=fxs_ks
context=default
channel=1-20

#include dahdi-channels.conf
```

any help

thanks..

Thanks  a lot...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `exten => s,5,Set(CALLERID(num,CID)=${CALLERID})` is not valid, it should read: `exten => s,5,Set(CALLERID(num)=${CALLERID})`. Second, setting CALLERID to CALLERID is redundant. Third, are you actually setting the callerid in the first place (that would happen in your `default` context)?